# Can i show <?PHP ?>, <SCRIPT> tag in html page

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to develop an application question forum, where user can submit their answer . But i've stuck in one place where,

I've a textarea which take a user input , user can type anything they want including html tag, script tag, php tag. and store it in database. After that when i fetches the data i'm showing it inside  tag.

`<div><?php echo $answere;?></div>`

My problem is that when user write `<?php ?> tag or <script>` tag in answer textarea it's getting saved properly in database but it showing nothing.

When i fetch and wrap my database saved answer in textarea it's showing proper result.

**Example:**

if some one write below text in answer textarea

```
<?php
 // SOME CODE
?>
```

**Result**

Inside div it's showing nothing.

Inside textarea area it's showing proper result.

**Note :** I'm not using htmlentities(), html_entity_decode()

Can anyone point me right me direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your **Note** is the answer I'd say. You *should* be using `htmlspecialchars()` when you want raw html to appear as plain text within your html page.

Comment: But His note is about entities, not special characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the native `highlight_string` for PHP:

```
echo highlight_string($code);
```

For more information, have a look at the documentation here: http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

For JavaScript, you'll need to find a plugin for highlighting code, but if you just want to display unhighlighted code, you can use `htmlspecialchars()` for that.

One such plugin for PHP is [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) which has quite a few different languages supported in addition to JavaScript.